# asp.net global.asax and map page route

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making an asp.net web application using notepad. I do not want to use visual studio so please do not suggest that.

I am trying to make my URL's SEO friendly, and am trying to implement a `global.asax` page which I can use to implement `MapPageRoute`.

Below is the whole of my `global.asax` page eg there is no other code on this page except for what is below:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>

<script runat="server">

    void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("","/about","~/about.aspx");
    }

</script>
```

The intention is that when the user goes to:

```
www.mywebsite.co.uk/about
```

they are redirected to the page:

```
www.mywebsite.co.uk/about.aspx
```

From my experience with `MapPageRoute`, I have implemented this properly.

However, I am getting a 404 file not found error, so it is obvisouly not working properly.

Is it that I need to compile this page before it will work properly, or do I need to lay it out differently, or is it something else?

Or is my `MapPageRoute` layout incorrect?

Comment: I think you need to give it a name (1st parameter) that is not null or empty.  You will not see the `.aspx` in the address bar at all, but your assumptions are correct.  However, make sure you are actually registering the routes from Global.asax in the `Application_Start` method or whatever your startup routine is.

Comment: @ps2goat if you put 'register the route' as the answer I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the route a name (1st parameter) that is not null or empty. You will not see the .aspx in the address bar at all, but your assumptions are correct. However, make sure you are actually registering the routes from Global.asax in the Application_Start method or whatever your startup routine is.